# UIScrollView adding two unwanted UIImageViews on touch out of nowhere

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have noticed some strange behaviour for a UIScrollView.

In a new XCode(4.6.2 on OS X 10.8.4) iOS project, I've only added a RootViewController, with one line of custom code: adding a UIScrollView as a subview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.view addSubview:[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]];
}
```

Then after touching the screen once, when I inspect the view hierarchy in lldb, the output is as follows.

```
(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
$0 = 0x07126f10 <UIWindow: 0x7528660; frame = (0 0; 320 568); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7528730>>
   | <UIView: 0x7668580; frame = (0 20; 320 548); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7668910>>
   |    | <UIScrollView: 0x7666200; frame = (0 0; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7666df0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x76624f0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x11121a30; frame = (313 541; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x11121b60>> - (null)
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x11121bd0; frame = (313 541; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x11121c70>> - (null)
```

Suddenly the UIScrollView has two subviews which I did not add myself. This happens both in the simulator and on the device (also both iPhone and iPad).

So my question is:
Is this normal behaviour? If so, why would it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the scroll indicators. One UIImageView for the horizontal indicator and another one for the vertical indicator.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the scroll indicators. These details shouldn't really matter, since you should be using the scrollview's .contentView to hold your own subviews.